# Twitter card not working even after validation

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, metadata

I want to add a Twitter button on my website to share  content, as well as a Twitter card. I've already added the meta tags.

Here is the code for my share button:

```
  <a  href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http://176.32.230.11/trialandtest.com/" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://176.32.230.11/trialandtest.com/" data-via="dasf" data-hashtags="iwishican" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
```

This is the code for the meta tags I've added as well:

```
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://176.32.230.11/trialandtest.com/assets/images/profile-img.jpg">
```

Here is the link to my site:

http://176.32.230.11/trialandtest.com/

I'd be grateful if someone could assist me as to where I am going wrong, because I have my URL whitelisted on Twitter, but when I try to share something it does not share the content on the preview window and shares the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Your share url should be dynamic. I think when you click on the share button it is taking your static url ie. http://176.32.230.11/trialandtest.com

Comment: thanks for your time ... i thought that might be the problem but i used numerous other share button codes like

Comment: it still doesnt work.. even if i share the link directly on twitter it does not work